# Primefaces autocomplete ClassCastException

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I am using Spring 3, Hibernate 4 and JSF 2.0 and am trying to do primefaces autocomplete.

I have the following in DAO class to get values from Oracle function

```
@Override
    public List<EmployeeDetail> getEmployeeDetails(String employeeNumber) {

        List query = (List)entityManager.createNamedQuery("getEmp")
                .setParameter("empNumber", employeeNumber)
                .getSingleResult();

        return query;

    }
```

Converter class

```
public EmployeeNameConverter(

            List<EmployeeDetail> employeeDB, EmployeeDetailService instance,
                    String employeeNumber) {
                if (employeeDetailService == null) {
                    employeeDetailService = instance;
                }
                if (param == null) {
                    param = employeeNumber;
                }
                this.employeeDB = employeeDB;
            }

@Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1,
            String submittedValue) {
        if (submittedValue.trim().equals("")) {
            return null;
        } else {
            try {
                // int number = Integer.parseInt(submittedValue);
                employeeDB = getEmployeeDetailService().getEmployeeDetails(param);
                for (EmployeeDetail emp : employeeDB) {
                    if (emp.getEmployeeNumber() == submittedValue) {
                        return emp;
                    }
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(
                        FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error",
                        "Not a valid employee"));
            }
        }
```

In my Managedbean

I have complete method where I am passing employeeDetailService to my converter class.

```
public List<EmployeeDetail> complete(String query) {
        List<EmployeeDetail> suggestions;
        suggestions = new ArrayList<EmployeeDetail>();
        try {
            employee =  (List<EmployeeDetail>) new EmployeeNameConverter(
                    employeeList, employeeDetailService, query);

            for (EmployeeDetail p : employee) {
                if (p.getEmployeeNumber().startsWith(query))
                    suggestions.add(p);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exc " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return suggestions;
    }
```

JSF Code

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{empMB.selectedEmployee}"
                            id="basicPojo" minQueryLength="6" 
                            completeMethod="#{empMB.complete}" var="p"
                            itemLabel="#{p.employeeNumber}" 
                            itemValue="#{p}" converter="#{p.employee}"
                            forceSelection="true" />
```

When I type in characters I am getting exception

```
EmployeeNameConverter cannot be cast to java.util.List
java.lang.ClassCastException: net.test.util.EmployeeNameConverter cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

How can I resolve this? Is this the correct approach or could someone kindly suggest better approach in achieving the same?

Update 1

```
@Override
    public List<EmployeeDetail> getEmployeeDetails(String employeeNumber) {

        List query = (List)entityManager.createNamedQuery("getEmp")
                .setParameter("empNumber", employeeNumber)
                .getSingleResult();

        return query;

    }
```

**Exception**

```
net.test.entity.EmployeeDetail cannot be cast to java.util.List
java.lang.ClassCastException: net.test.entity.EmployeeDetail cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at net.test.dao.EmployeeDetailDAOImpl.getEmployeeDetails(EmployeeDetailDAOImpl.java:36)
```

and exception line is

```
List query = (List)entityManager.createNamedQuery("getEmp")
                    .setParameter("empNumber", employeeNumber)
                    .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Is `p.employee` supposed to be an implementation of converter or a DTO?

Comment: @kolossus How can I refer employee variable of converter class? Because if I directly give as employee then I will get an error as my <p:autoComplete is in a dialog of another page.

Comment: why do you want the converter as a property on the service? this is definetly a wrong approach. the converter should be attached just the normal way, like `converter="#{employeeNameConverter}`. the complete method should just lookup the EmployeeDetails list.

Comment: @fischermatte I have changed to converter="#{employeeNameConverter}, still same error. I am passing service to Converter class because this is not a managed bean so if I do not pass service object I wouldn't be able to access DAO method in Converter class.

Comment: @Polppan, To eliminate probable causes, 1)annotate your converter with `@ManagedBean` to be able to inject a datasource (maybe an EJB?) 2)Try to refactor your converter to do without the constructor arguments. This is the only point in your code where the converter has anything to do with a List (I think), and judging from the exception, it's a List cast that is causing the conversion to choke. Can you also pinpoint specifically at what point in the conversion code the exception is thrown?

Comment: since you are using spring - you could define the converter as a bean (via xml or by using annotation @Component). after doing so you can inject other beans like your DAOs or Services into the converter. note that you have to register SpringBeanFacesELResolver in faces-config.xml, in order to access spring beans from JSF pages via EL.

Comment: @kolossus Cast exception is thrown at this line `employee =  (List<EmployeeDetail>) new EmployeeNameConverter(
                    employeeList, employeeDetailService, query);`

Comment: @Polppan, well there is your problem. You have absolutely no business instantiating a converter by hand, much less trying to cast it to a `List` of any kind. It's the container's responsibility to manage and instantiate a converter.

Comment: @kolossus So from your previous comment, point number one is the way to go?

Comment: @Polppan, yes it is. It's not best practice(I seem to forget exactly what is) , but it'll work.

Comment: @kolossus I have put '@Named("name")'
'@ViewAccessScoped' made in converter class. Now I am getting another classcastexception in DAO class. I have put the details as Update by editing my orginal question.

Comment: @kolossus I have managed to resolve all exceptions, till bit more work left. If you could kindly provide an answer regarding your comments, I will be happy and glad to accept it. Many thanks

Comment: @Polppan, we might need to continue this in chat shortly, but the cause of your exception is pretty straightforward, your JPA query is returning an entity of type `EmployeeDetail` and you're attempting to cast it to a `List`. Why?

Comment: @kolossus I have managed to resolve all cast exceptions and it is working fine, of course some minor tweaking has to be done. Like I mentioned in my previous comment, if you could provide an answer with what you have mentioned in your comments, I will be happy and glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main issues apparent here

1. You're attempting to instantiate and manage a JSF converter instance by hand. Don't do this. The converter is a construct designed for use by the JSF context only. It's not the job of you the developer to call `new` or supply constructor arguments to the converter class. Implement a simple converter per [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/) and configure on the `<p:autoComplete/>`

   From your comments, the reason you've taken to managing the converter by hand is to be able to access your DAO layer. As a workaround, you can add `@ManagedBean` to your converter and JSF will treat is as a managed bean *and* a converter. Being a managed bean, you'll now be able to inject your DAO resource into it. This is not best practice, but only a workaround. This limitation on converters will be removed in JSF2.2 though :).
2. While manipulating the converter, you're attempting to treat it like a regular POJO and trying to cast it into several incompatible types as a result

   ```
    employee = (List<EmployeeDetail>) new EmployeeNameConverter( employeeList, employeeDetailService, query); //EmployeeNameConverter !instanceof EmployeeDetail
   ```